# iptables port forwarding to localhost

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables

On my linux server, using iptables on the same box, I'd like to redirect traffic to my external interface on port 1234/tcp to the loopback interface on 32400/tcp in order to hide plex server default port.
I can't apply filtering based on IP addresses, as I'm using this from different IPs.

I'm doing this:

```
# enables forwarding output traffic from eth0 to 1234/tcp to 127.0.0.1:32400 tcp
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:32400
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
# let the kernel accept public IPs accessing loopback interface
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
```

This only works if I keep port 32400/tcp allowed to the external traffic using:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

I only want to have 1234/tcp open to the outside and block 32400/tcp
Any idea on why I'm failing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to meet your goal, just specify the interfaces where the port should be allowed.

In your case limiting 32400 to loopback interface by adding `-i lo` should do the trick:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
```

Please take into account that you are adding rules with `-I` and you didn't paste a whole ruleset, and it might be relevant.

Also, you may consider just reconfiguring your service to use a port different from 32400.